# Should I close TCP connection manually after terminate process?

Tags: network-programming, posix

Assume I write a program ，and the program  create tcp after start up  ，my question is ，should I write code to close tcp connections before I close the program .Or,os can close TCP connections belong to terminated program automatically?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the Linux *kernel* as you tagged. You could possibly have the generic `linux` tag, or the `posix` tag, and probably the `network-programming` tag. And your title says "after" program termination, while your question says "before". It can't be both and it can't definitely not be done *after* the program is terminated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks ,already re-edited

Comment: As for the problem, modern multi-tasking desktop and server operating systems release almost all resources a process creates or uses, including sockets. *However* it's also a good habit to always clean up after yourself. If you acquire a resource, you should also release it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the operating system will eventually close the connection, doing so in your code has the advantages of expediting the closure (e.g. making the other end aware of it sooner) and releasing buffers and other TCP state info earlier, preventing lack of such space blocking subsequent connections (for other programs).